# How many virtual processors in a Azure App Service Plan?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I'm trying to convert and maybe there's no simple analog.
I have an Azure App Service plan with a P3V2 pricing tier.  It has an a total ACU of 840.  My web application is highly parallel and is optimized for 32 threads.  On these application servers, how many actual CPUs are available to independently run my 32 threads?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Azure Pricing for App Service page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/app-service/windows/), the P3V2 plan has 4 CPU cores each instance.